# Concatenate URL in XSL

Tags: html, url, xslt, string-concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate a url together in xsl. Basically, I'm taking two variables and incorporating those into the pieces of the link to make things dynamic. How can I perform this concatenation?

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at [XPath Functions Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_functions.asp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<a href="{concat('http://',$string1,'/',$string2)}>link</a>
```

Depends on the variables and on the target URL, but you want to use `concat()` anyway.

Comment: Note that this is a crude string concatenation. To correctly construct a hierarchic URL from arbitrary parts, you really want something a bit more sophisticated. In XSLT 2.0, consider using escape-uri() (various flavours) and resolve-uri().